# Just can't remove hover after mouseout

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need when mouseout from element it's come active first li.

I'm trying to hide the current element: `$(this).find('a').tab('hide');`
But it has no effect.

```js
$('.nav-tabs > li').mouseover( function(){
  $(this).find('a').tab('show');
});

$('.nav-tabs > li').mouseout( function(){
  $(this).find('a').tab('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab4">Account</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      TAB1 CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      TAB2 OTHER CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
      TAB3 MORE CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
      TAB4 SO MUCH CONTENT
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the first tab then you use tab to select it.

```js
$('.nav-tabs > li').mouseover( function(){
  $(this).find('a').tab('show');
});
$('.nav-tabs > li').mouseout( function(){
  $('a[href="#tab1"]').tab('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab4">Account</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      TAB1 CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      TAB2 OTHER CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
      TAB3 MORE CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
      TAB4 SO MUCH CONTENT
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can use to hide your tab this way by retrieving a tab reference and hiding when removing the mouse.

Follow the example below.

```js
$('.nav-tabs > li').mouseover( function(){
    $('a', this).tab('show');
});
$('.nav-tabs > li').mouseout( function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');

    const tab = $('a', this).attr('href');
    $(tab).removeClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab3">Messages</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab4">Account</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
          TAB1 CONTENT
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
          TAB2 OTHER CONTENT
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
          TAB3 MORE CONTENT
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
          TAB4 SO MUCH CONTENT
      </div>  
  </div>
```